# Update query to remove from file structure and database

Tags: sql, sql-update, db2, db2-400

I'm running an update query to remove an image from a structure and the reference of it in the database. It works for the file structure but it doesn't remove the string value in the field. The query looks like:

```
"Update MYTable set IMAGE_FULL  = COALESCE(IMAGE_FULL, '') where    prprcd = '" . $prodCode ."' and prcucd = '". $cust ."'";
```

So the image is removed from the file structure but not from IMAGE_FULL(field name) the value of the image still shows(the name eg. "pic.png"), what do i need to do in order to remove from both places, how can i get this done?

Comment: Side note: string concatenation leaves you open to SQL Injection.  You should be using host variables and parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

The coalesce(IMAGE_FULL,'') will always return the current value in IMAGE_FULL, unless the field is null. I think you want it filled with null or '', isn't it?

```
"Update MYTable set IMAGE_FULL  = '' where    prprcd = '" . $prodCode ."' and prcucd = '". $cust ."'";
```

or

```
"Update MYTable set IMAGE_FULL  = NULL where    prprcd = '" . $prodCode ."' and prcucd = '". $cust ."'";
```

Comment: I tried NULL but it doesn't work, only removes the image in the fill structure not the string in the database field